# Ionic iOS App Error - Custom Scheme URIs are not allowed for 'WEB' client type

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, google-plus-signin

I am using this plugin.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

The implementation works fine for android. But google sign in on iOS opens safari webview and throws 400 invalid_request.

I am using the ios client id and reverse client id generated on google developer console.

Anyways to debug or know what the issue is?

Comment: I don't know if this fixes the issue, but I was able to fix it by using web client id instead of android or ios client id.

Answer (score 2):

The usual cause of this error is having an incorrect REVERSE_CLIENT_ID.  Double check that you have the REVERSE_CLIENT_ID from the plist file downloaded when you set up the iOS application registration on the Google developer console.  Note that if you got it wrong, *changing* this is difficult, as it gets copied into various locations and won't update automatically if you just try to change it in `config.xml`.  When I mistakenly used my Android client ID to set up the plugin, I found that as well as `config.xml` I also needed to change the top level `package.json` file, and the `<appname>-Info.plist` in the `platforms/ios` directory in order to get the correct ID used.

Comment: Whenever you need to change the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID, you need to remove the plugin first and then add it again with the new REVERSED_CLIENT_ID, e.g: `ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-googleplus` then followed by `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --save --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=new_reversed_client_id`

Comment: Solution has been discuss in this thread: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/309