# Custom scheme URIs are not allowed for 'Web' client type - Google with Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, gidsignin

I am trying to implement google sign in using firebase in to my iOS app. I follow this tutorial. 
    https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin
I have setup the iOS app in firebase and use the google clientID and reversedClientID from the dowloaded GoogleService-Info.plist.

FYI: I have a custom sign-in button instead of the google sign in button. Anyway when i click the sign in button, google following error display in a webview.

[image]

I know my problem is the same as which described in this question.

[Google 400 Error: invalid request Custom scheme URIs are not allowed for 'Web' client type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269251/google-400-error-invalid-request-custom-scheme-uris-are-not-allowed-for-web-c)

But, in my case, I have created the app in Firebase still I get the error. Any idea please...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first step is to check if you have already the OAuth 2.0 ID for iOS. To do this please open the [Credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) in the API Console. I hope you will find *iOS client for your application* under **OAuth 2.0 client IDs** section. If not, please follow this [Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#creatingcred)
The second step is to replace the *Web Client ID* with in *iOS Client ID* from **OAuth 2.0 client IDs** section. To do this, you should open the **GoogleService-Info.plist** and modify following keys: **CLIENT_ID** with **[value].apps.googleusercontent.com** and **REVERSED_CLIENT_ID** with **com.googleusercontent.apps.[value]**.

Comment: Yes. I found ios app in Credentials page. But its very confusing because, in firebase I have created an ios app too. But firebase given a web client id. Google makes everything confusing

Comment: @sajaz I know, this is strange. Me too, I had the same experience with the GIDSignIn.

Comment: Following this thread. I've also created my app from Firebase but it provides a WEB clientId? WTF?
I have signed my app with an SHA for Android and created the iOS key as @ValeriyKliuk said. It works, but it generates different clientIds among platforms.
Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760596/ionic-ios-app-error-custom-scheme-uris-are-not-allowed-for-web-client-type/43366712#43366712
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you're using `flutterfire ui` package you need to change the client id parameter in your GoogleProviderConfiguration class with the iOS client id,
you can copy it from here [Credential page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=)

example:

```dart
providerConfigs: [
        GoogleProviderConfiguration(
            clientId: "your copied key here"),
]
```

re-build you're app and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced this same issue using flutterfire_ui on Flutter.
The error appears to be from a couple of things. As Valeriy points out you need the ios client ID. But I still got the error if I used the scopes

```
openid
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
```

Instead change these to

```
openid
email
profile
```

Strangely the opposite is true for Android, where the WebID and the first of the scopes should be used.

It also pays to be aware of the OAuth Content Screen..
In google cloud go to APIs & Services > OAuth consent screen > Edit.
You can add scopes here and fix any missing required fields that Firebase might not be filling out (I had 1). I believe this takes a while to propagate after a change, so give it an hour.